# How to configure HTTP request (POST & GET) on apache in centos 7

Tags: php, apache, centos, http-headers, yii2-basic-app

I have a Yii2 web application running OK in Data Center(DC) server(centos 7, PHP 7.3.26, MySQL 5.7.33 & Apache 2.4.6), and I configured another server as Data Recovery(DR) (centos 7, PHP 7.3.33, MySQL 5.7.36 & Apache 2.4.6) then I copied the same application from DC to DR without changing source code, in DR it starts well and I can login and navigate in menus successful but all services involving REST-API are not working and it stays silent while in DC are working fine.

I guess, I have not configured something well in DR Apache to handle HTTP request or REST API. Anyone with an idea on where should I touch regarding server configuration?

Comment: Please check [help/on-topic] and [ask] - on top of lacking details about your configuration, this does _not_ seem to be _programming-_ but configuration related (see also the [tag:apache] documentation), thus off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: As nobody knows what you mean by "not working", it's close to impossible to provide help